# Submit Value from price calculator

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an order form that should filled with identity and price calculated with javascript. But I have no idea how to submit the calculated value to php file.
This is the code :

```html
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="1020">
  <form action="kirim.php" method="POST" >
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><h2>Form Pemesanan</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="80">Nama</td>
      <td><input name="nama" type="text" id="nama" size="30" required="true"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Nomor HP</td>
      <td><input name="nomor" type="text" id="nomor" size="30" required="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Email</p> </td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" required="true"></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><center>Nama Server</center></td><td><center>Masa Aktif</center></td><td><center>Jumlah (Rp.)</center></td><td><center>Diskon (Rp.)</center></td>
 <tr>
   <td>Server</td>
   <td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="server1" value="SSH AMERIKA (Nodes Direct)">SSH AMERIKA (Nodes Direct)
   </td>
   <td width="450">
    <input onclick="hitung(this.value)" type="radio" id="a1" name="serverr1" value="10000">1 bulan
    <input onclick="hitung(this.value)" type="radio" id="a2" name="serverr1" value="25000">3 bulan
    <input onclick="hitung(this.value)" type="radio" id="a3" name="serverr1" value="50000">6 bulan
    <input onclick="hitung(this.value)" type="radio" id="a4" name="serverr1" value="75000">9 bulan
    <input onclick="hitung(this.value)" type="radio" id="a5" name="serverr1" value="100000">12 bulan</td>
    <td width="120" id="amerika"></td>
    <td width="100" id="amerika2"></td>
   <tr>
  </form>
</table>

<script>
var harga=0, harga2=0, harga3=0, harga4=0, hargasementara=0, hargasementara2=0, hargasementara3=0, hargasementara4=0;
//------------------------------------------------------HITUNG RADIO BUTTON 1-----------------------------------------------
function hitung(){
var hargasementara;
if (document.getElementById('a1').checked) {
hargasementara=10000;
harga=document.getElementById('a1').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('a2').checked){
hargasementara=30000;
harga=document.getElementById('a2').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('a3').checked){
hargasementara=60000;
harga=document.getElementById('a3').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('a4').checked){
hargasementara=90000;
harga=document.getElementById('a4').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('a5').checked) {
hargasementara=120000;
harga=document.getElementById('a5').value;
}
else {
hargasementara=0;
}
document.getElementById("amerika").innerHTML = hargasementara;
document.getElementById("amerika2").innerHTML = hargasementara-harga;
akhir();
}
//------------------------------------------------------HITUNG RADIO BUTTON 2-----------------------------------------------
function hitung2(){
var hargasementara2;
if (document.getElementById('i1').checked) {
hargasementara2=15000;
harga2=document.getElementById('i1').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('i2').checked) {
hargasementara2=45000;
harga2=document.getElementById('i2').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('i3').checked) {
hargasementara2=90000;
harga2=document.getElementById('i3').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('i4').checked) {
hargasementara2=135000;
harga2=document.getElementById('i4').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('i5').checked) {
hargasementara2=180000;
harga2=document.getElementById('i5').value;
} else {
hargasementara2=0;
}
document.getElementById("indonesia").innerHTML = hargasementara2;
document.getElementById("indonesia2").innerHTML = hargasementara2-harga2;
akhir();
}
//------------------------------------------------------HITUNG RADIO BUTTON 3-----------------------------------------------
function hitung3(){
var hargasementara3;
if (document.getElementById('s1').checked) {
hargasementara3=15000;
harga3=document.getElementById('s1').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('s2').checked) {
hargasementara3=45000;
harga3=document.getElementById('s2').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('s3').checked) {
hargasementara3=90000;
harga3=document.getElementById('s3').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('s4').checked) {
hargasementara3=135000;
harga3=document.getElementById('s4').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('s5').checked) {
hargasementara3=180000;
harga3=document.getElementById('s5').value;
} else {
hargasementara3=0;
}
document.getElementById("singapura").innerHTML = hargasementara3;
document.getElementById("singapura2").innerHTML = hargasementara3-harga3;
akhir();
}
//------------------------------------------------------HITUNG RADIO BUTTON 4-----------------------------------------------
function hitung4(){
var hargasementara4;
if (document.getElementById('ss1').checked) {
hargasementara4=20000;
harga4=document.getElementById('ss1').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('ss2').checked) {
hargasementara4=60000;
harga4=document.getElementById('ss2').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('ss3').checked) {
hargasementara4=120000;
harga4=document.getElementById('ss3').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('ss4').checked) {
hargasementara4=180000;
harga4=document.getElementById('ss4').value;
} else if (document.getElementById('ss5').checked) {
hargasementara4=240000;
harga4=document.getElementById('ss5').value;
} else {
hargasementara4=0;
}
document.getElementById("singapuraa").innerHTML = hargasementara4;
document.getElementById("singapuraa2").innerHTML = hargasementara4-harga4;
akhir();
}

function akhir(){
hargaakhir=harga*1+harga2*1+harga3*1+harga4*1;
document.getElementById("jumlah").innerHTML = hargaakhir;
}
</script>
<p> Jumlah Total Setelah Diskon:</p>
<p id="jumlah"></p>

</body>
```

So, I want hargaakhir variable (result of calculation) is submitted with the form to kirim.php

Thanks before,

Comment: as well as showing he value on screen, write it to a hidden form input, then it will be submitted with the form

Comment: Security tip: you shouldn't use or any client-side language for calculations that need to be correct, especially ones involving money.

Comment: If they are not verified by the server.

Comment: OK, I will take care @DavidCorbin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as well as writing to the html element *jumlah* create a hidden form input

```
<input type="hidden" name="sum" value="">
```

populate it with the js and retrieve after the form was submitted with  `$_POST['sum']`

Answer (score -1):

In your "kirim.php" if you do

```
echo $_POST['serverr1'];
```

you'll get the form value since in your radio button you define the element name as "serverr1"

Comment: i mean variable that hold the result of calculation. Thanks it's already solved with hidden input.